# Is there a (simple) command to query the module that provided an installed package in SLE 15?

Tags: linux, suse

SLE (SLES, SLED) 15 introduced a modular design, where packages can originate from a set of different "modules".
To install such a package the corresponding module has to be "enabled" (e.g. via `SUSEConnect`).

There is a command to list the modules enabled (`SUSEConnect --list-extensions`), but I could not find a command to query the "module origin" of an installed package (My initial guess that RPM query tag `DISTURL` would reveal it proved wrong).

Is there a command to find out the module that provided an installed RPM package, or a command that lists all packages installed from a specific module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason I couldn't find the solution earlier was nomenclature:
While SUSE calls it "modules", there are basically just separate "repositories" (that may need additional licenses/subscriptions).

So the trick is to filter on repositories like this:

```bash
MOD_BASE=SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2
zypper packages --installed-only --repo ${MOD_BASE}-Pool --repo ${MOD_BASE}-Updates
```

(The second repository contains the package updates, and maybe you could leave that out)

Output might look like this:

```text
Refreshing service 'Basesystem_Module_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Desktop_Applications_Module_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Development_Tools_Module_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Legacy_Module_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_High_Availability_Extension_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'SUSE_Linux_Enterprise_Server_for_SAP_Applications_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'SUSE_Package_Hub_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Refreshing service 'Server_Applications_Module_15_SP2_x86_64'.
Building repository 'SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Pool' cache ...................................................................................................................................................................[done]
Building repository 'SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Updates' cache ................................................................................................................................................................[done]
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
S  | Repository                      | Name                      | Version         | Arch
---+---------------------------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-------
i+ | SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Updates | ntp                       | 4.2.8p15-4.19.1 | x86_64
v  | SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Updates | ntp                       | 4.2.8p15-4.16.1 | x86_64
v  | SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Updates | ntp                       | 4.2.8p15-4.13.1 | x86_64
v  | SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Updates | ntp                       | 4.2.8p15-4.10.1 | x86_64
v  | SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Pool    | ntp                       | 4.2.8p13-4.6.1  | x86_64
i+ | SLE-Module-Legacy15-SP2-Pool    | sle-module-legacy-release | 15.2-44.1       | x86_64
```